# const specifier to the user defined data type in C

Tags: c, embedded, misra

I have user defined data type

```
typedef Unsigned int8  COMMAND_TYPE[6];
```

now I have function like

```
ConnectCommand(COMMAND_TYPE const command)
{
}
```

When try to run static analyzer check I get an Misra warning that "The object addressed by the pointer parameter 'command' is not modified and so the pointer could be of type 'pointer to const'"
This  is violation of Misra rule 16.7

Though const specifier is used and it appears its not seen here by the misra rule checkin tool and why ?

Comment: 8 bit unsigned integer

Comment: @KeithThompson Probably he mean [This](http://de.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/int8.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com).

Comment: @Michi: Unlikely, that's a function.

Comment: For that matter, what is `Unsigned`?

Comment: I just wanted to say data type as  unsigned integer 8 thats it .

Comment: Don't use homebrew types (`int8`) which are already in the standard library. See `stdint.h`/`inttypes.h`! ANd the name `int8` for an **unsigned** type is very missleading.

Comment: You cannot qualify an array `const`, only its elements.

Comment: @Omprasad The answer may differ between C C++, suggest selecting one only.

Comment: Besides the `uint8_t` goof-up and the missing return type of the function, I get the feeling this is not the actual code at all. Are you sure that the real function does not take a pointer as parameter, rather than an array? _Copy/paste the actual code_.

Answer (score 3):

Certain this is a static analyzer check problem.

The below do the same and both should pass your checker.

```
ConnectCommand(COMMAND_TYPE const command)
ConnectCommand(const COMMAND_TYPE command)
```

Although legal code, using a `typedef` of an array, confused your checker.  IMO, this *is* a design style best avoided.

---

Making this community wiki for reference.  Suggest deleting once a a good answer comes along.

On review I suspect the problem is Misra - it is giving a false warning.  #2, and #3 commented below do the same thing.  #4 is redundant with #2, #3.

I will be either deleting this answer or re-work it correctly.

Suggest attempting

```
typedef       Unsigned int8       COMMAND_TYPE[6];
typedef const Unsigned int8 CONST_COMMAND_TYPE[6];

void ConnectCommand(CONST_COMMAND_TYPE command) {
  ...
}

  COMMAND_TYPE c;
  ConnectCommand(c);
```

---

`const` in `ConnectCommand(COMMAND_TYPE const command) { ...}` refers to a `const` `command`.  `command` is a pointer to objects of type `COMMAND_TYPE`.  `const command` implies that the pointer should not change in the `ConnectCommand()` function body.

The "const" in the warning "... type pointer to const" recommends using a `const` to the type of object pointed *to* by `command`.  This is because the data pointed to by `command` is not changed.

```
//             add              could drop this const
//              |                   |
ConnectCommand(const COMMAND_TYPE const command)
```

Comment: my bad not to mention that i tried adding ConnectCommand(const COMMAND_TYPE command) and resulted in same error.

Comment: @Omprasad  There are 4 candidates: 1) `ConnectCommand(COMMAND_TYPE command)` 2) `ConnectCommand(COMMAND_TYPE const command)` 3) `ConnectCommand(const COMMAND_TYPE command)` 4)`ConnectCommand(const COMMAND_TYPE const command)`.  Does #4 result in a warning?  Was the "resulted in same error" using #3 the _exact_ same error?

Comment: @ chux: I did try solution no 3 and 4 which resulted in same error as posted. At this point do you suspect my static analyzer tool i do so !!!

Comment: @Omprasad Yes, posted is a suggested work-around.  A higher level issue is using an array as a `typedef`:  recommend against that.  Various alternatives exist.  Advise if that is an option.